# Exceptions and Output

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

I have problem when calling my function, I am receiving bad output as I will explain later in the text.

These are the resources I am working with:

```
Main_Building=[10,12,14,17,21,25,30,36,43,52,62,74,89,107,128,154,185,222,266,319,383,460,552,662,795,954,1145,1374,1648,1978]
Barracks=[16,19,23,28,33,40,48,57,69,83,99,119,143,171,205,247,296,355,426,511,613,736,883,1060,1272]
Stables=[20,24,29,35,41,50,60,72,86,103,124,149,178,214,257,308,370,444,532,639]
Workshop=[24,29,35,41,50,60,72,86,103,124,149,178,214,257,308]
Blacksmith=[19,23,27,33,39,47,57,68,82,98,118,141,169,203,244,293,351,422,506,607]
Market=[10,12,14,17,21,25,30,36,43,52,62,74,89,107,128,154,185,222,266,319,383,460,552,662,795]
Axe=[6,7,9,10,12,15,18,21,26,31,37,45,53,64,77,92,111,133,160,192,230,276,331,397,477,572,687,824,989,1187]
Clay_Pit=[6,7,9,10,12,15,18,21,26,31,37,45,53,64,77,92,111,133,160,192,230,276,331,397,477,572,687,824,989,1187]
Mine=[6,7,9,10,12,15,18,21,26,31,37,45,53,64,77,92,111,133,160,192,230,276,331,397,477,572,687,824,989,1187]
Settler_House=[5,6,7,9,10,12,15,18,21,26,31,37,45,53,64,77,92,111,133,160,192,230,276,331,397,477,572,687,824,989]
Warehouse=[6,7,9,10,12,15,18,21,26,31,37,45,53,64,77,92,111,133,160,192,230,276,331,397,477,572,687,824,989,1187]
Wall=[8,10,12,14,17,20,24,29,34,41,50,59,71,86,103,123,148,177,213,256]
```

Here is my code:

```
def buildings(points):
    for i in range(0,30):
        try:
            if Main_Building[i]>=points:
                del Main_Building[i:]
            if Barracks[i]>=points:
                del Barracks[i:]
            if Stables[i]>=points:
                del Stables[i:]
            if Workshop[i]>=points:
                del Workshop[i:]
            if Blacksmith[i]>=points:
                del Blacksmith[i:]
            if Market[i]>=points:
                del Market[i:]
            if Axe[i]>=points:
                del Axe[i:]
            if Clay_Pit[i]>=points:
                del Clay_Pit[i:]
            if Mine[i]>=points:
                del Mine[i:]
            if Settler_House[i]>=points:
                del Settler_House[i:]
            if Warehouse[i]>=points:
                del Warehouse[i:]
            if Wall[i]>=points:
                del Wall[i:]                  
        except IndexError:
            continue
```

The problem is when the it comes to Condition of Blacksmith, it looks to me as the condition is only passed, and the same for others continuing to Wall condition. The condition is determining where to stop and delete rest of the list for further use. The lists are different lengths so I used simple exception for when it is out of range it just skips and continue to next condition.

Suggested output when def buildings(100):

```
Blacksmith=[19,23,27,33,39,47,57,68,82,98]
```

Actual output is whole list without any change. The same applies to continuing condition.

What I tried:

1. I tried to restart Python but that unfortunately was not it.
2. If I misspelled the variable name.
3. Redoing spacing on every condition.

Maybe solution but not effective, adding to each condition try exception ?(Not a good Idea in my opinion).

Why it skips the conditions ?

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Continue` will return to the beginning of current loop and grab next index. This means that if an error occurred halfway, the last half is skipped. It was also quite lengthy. Here is my solution.

```
data = [Main_Building, Barracks, Stables, Workshop, Blacksmith, Market, Axe, Clay_Pit, Mine, Settler_House, Warehouse, Wall]
def buildings(points):
    for building in data: # loop through each building seperately, shortens code and removes arbitrary loop number
        for point in building: # loop through each buildings index, same as your code
            if point >= points:
                del building[building.index(point):]
buildings(20)
print data
```

Comment: Thank you, now I get it. What a crappy mistake I made.

Answer (score 0):

If any error occured between `try-except`, Python will pass or continue all of the codes between `try-except`.

```
try:
    a = int(input("integer: "))
    print("print this")
    print("print that")
except:
    pass
```

Output:

```
>>> 
integer: ab
>>>
```

See that `print this` and `print that` not printed. You should catch the errors one by one.

```
try:
    a = int(input("integer: "))
except:
    pass
print("print this")
print("print that")

>>> 
integer: ab
print this
print that
>>>
```